# Problems with some code

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning Java right now I cannot seem to figure out these errors in this...

```
public class Input {

    Setter access = new Setter();
//                              ^ Error here: Syntax error on token ";", { expected 
//                                after this token.

    if (commandExc == fly) {
        access.flySetter();
    }
    else if (commandExc == xray) {
        access.xraySetter();
    }
} // < Error here: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Code should be wrapped in method, shouldn't be directly inside the class body.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a class like that. Your inner code must be inside a method.

Like this:

```
public class Input { // start of class

  public Input() {  // start of constructor
    Setter access = new Setter(); // this could be outside the method

    // commandExc, fly and xray should be initialized somewhere
    if (commandExc == fly) {
        access.flySetter();
    }
    else if (commandExc == xray) {
        access.xraySetter();
    }
  } // end of constructor

} // end of class
```

Constructors are special kind of methods where you put code to initialize the instances of your class. In this case I put the code inside the constructor of the class. But it could be inside any other method. You must check what makes more sense in your program.

As you are learning Java I recommend you to check this link, specially the "Trails Covering the Basics":
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: WOW, I completely forgot about using methods. Ive been very focused on the code syntax and whatnot. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :). I have added a link for the java tutorials. It is a good place to learn Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Input {

    Setter access = new Setter();

    public static void main(String args[]) {   //or any method
        if (commandExc == fly) {
            access.flySetter();
        }
        else if (commandExc == xray) {
            access.xraySetter();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't working inside a method.  Try putting the code in the `main` method of `Input`.  For example:

```
public class Input {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Setter access = new Setter();

    if (commandExc == fly) {
        access.flySetter();
    }
    else if (commandExc == xray) {
        access.xraySetter();
    }
  }
}
```

If this was meant to be an object, place the initialization part of `access` into a constructor method.  The location of the `if`/`else` depends on the desired implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the code in a method. Just like below:

```
public class Input {

  Setter access = new Setter();

  public static void main(String args[]){   //or any method
      if (commandExc == fly) {
          access.flySetter();
      }
      else if (commandExc == xray) {
          access.xraySetter();
      }
  }

}
```